# Having trouble installing jQuery into Eclipse

Tags: macos, java, eclipse, jquery, maven

I downloaded Eclipse, and I am trying to install jQuery in it. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734967/installing-jsdt-jquery-plugin-in-eclipse-kepler-4-3) on StackOverflow, and followed nielsvh's answer. I was able to build the project with Maven, but found trouble importing it into Eclipse. I got this error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: JSDT jQuery Integration 1.7.0 (org.eclipselabs.jsdt.jquery_feature.feature.group 1.7.0)
  Missing requirement: JSDT jQuery API 1.7.0 (org.eclipselabs.jsdt.jquery.api 1.7.0) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core [1.1.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JSDT jQuery Integration 1.7.0 (org.eclipselabs.jsdt.jquery_feature.feature.group 1.7.0)
    To: org.eclipselabs.jsdt.jquery.api [1.7.0]
```

I have already installed Web Tools:

[image: WDT Installed]

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

EDIT:

With McDonald's' help, I was able to get farther by reinstalling JSDT, but now I have a different error where it wants to uninstall JSDT.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: JSDT jQuery Integration 1.7.0 (org.eclipselabs.jsdt.jquery_feature.feature.group 1.7.0)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.9.0.v201706011953 (org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.9.0.v201706011953)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    JavaScript Development Tools Core 1.3.1.v201401291437 (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core 1.3.1.v201401291437)
    JavaScript Development Tools Core 2.0.300.v201703171536 (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core 2.0.300.v201703171536)
    JavaScript Development Tools Core 1.3.0.v201308282108 (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core 1.3.0.v201308282108)
    JavaScript Development Tools Core 1.1.202.v201208171701 (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core 1.1.202.v201208171701)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JavaScript Development Tools 2.1.0.v201706011953 (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature.feature.group 2.1.0.v201706011953)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core [2.0.300.v201703171536]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.9.0.v201706011953 (org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.9.0.v201706011953)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature.feature.group [2.1.0.v201706011953]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JSDT jQuery API 1.7.0 (org.eclipselabs.jsdt.jquery.api 1.7.0)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core [1.1.0,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JSDT jQuery Integration 1.7.0 (org.eclipselabs.jsdt.jquery_feature.feature.group 1.7.0)
    To: org.eclipselabs.jsdt.jquery.api [1.7.0]
```

Comment: Give this thread a read just in case it's as simple as that: https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/46 and I'm talking about the comment from "***paulvi commented on May 20, 2013***"

Comment: Well, I got farther than I did before with it. Now, instead of erroring out, it wants to uninstall the JDST. http://imgur.com/a/KxGsj Won't this just bring me back to where I started? Edit: Here's the new error: https://pastebin.com/mHpTQgCD